# Change of PhoneAccentColor not updating in running app Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

In my XAML I have the following code to create a TextBlock:

```
        <TextBlock Margin="102,145,106,239" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="A" FontSize="96" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="ATextblock">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
        </TextBlock>
```

When I run the app the TextBlock correctly starts with the current accent color.

Then I go to the Settings page and change the accent color to a new value.

When I finally go back to my app using the Back button the color of my TextBlock is still the old accent color.

Why isn't this automatically updating?

Thanks for any help/hints!

Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting it again from the home screen: I'd expect the new accent/theme colour is only picked up when you next start the application (not when you return to it via the back button).

If so this is working as expected on 7.1, as when you use the Back key you're returning to the old "dormant" process and the updated themes are not applied.

In 7.0 the application this would work as you'd expected as the application would have been tombstoned and the updated themes would have been reloaded in a new application process.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. Now I understand why the color doesn't get updated.
Because I really want the color to be updated when returning to the app, what would be the best strategy to accomplish this?

Comment: This isn't a solution to the problem. This is clearly a bug in the SDK. Native apps from Microsoft update. How are they doing this?